# Alternative to $.mobile.changePage or $.mobile.changePage(back)

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have this function: click: `function() { $.mobile.changePage('#Page');}` After a list element is clicked clicking  I need to go back exactly where I've been regardless of where the function is called. Somewath like `$.mobile.changePage(back);`
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is get back to the previous page in history; `history.go(-1);` should do that.

Comment: You mean like this?  click: function() { history.go(-1);}